# Java Thread start and run function

Tags: java, multithreading

I stumbled upon a doubt.
I understand the basic difference between `start()` and `run()` function in `Thread` class and `Runnable` interface.
In below code snippet.

```
public class ThreadTest extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            System.out.println("-->" + this.getName() + ", "+ i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadTest t1 = new ThreadTest();
        t1.setName("firstThread");
        ThreadTest t2 = new ThreadTest();
        t2.setName("secondThread");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-->firstThread, 0
-->secondThread, 0
-->firstThread, 1
-->secondThread, 1
-->firstThread, 2
-->secondThread, 2
```

If I change `t1.start()` and `t2.start()` to `t1.run()` and `t2.run()`. I get the below output:

```
-->firstThread, 0
-->firstThread, 1
-->firstThread, 2
-->secondThread, 0
-->secondThread, 1
-->secondThread, 2
```

I have 2 doubts here:

1. Why there is difference in output in case of `run()` and `start()`?
2. It's said that, `start()` method creates a new thread and then runs it, while `run()` method just runs the thread. Then what is `new` operator doing here? I suppose, `new` is creating the thread.

Can someone please clarify.

Comment: `run` doesn't execute a "new thread", it call's the thread's `run` method (which in this calls the `Runnable`s `run` method).  `start` schedules a new thread, which, when executing, will call it's `run` method (within the new thread context).  2. `new` creates a new instance of the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the given answers mostly are correct, there's something deficit here. So, I thought of adding that missing pieces in my answer. If you directly create a Thread and start it in your main thread, that thread will get executed and main thread immediately continues to the next instruction. On the contrary, if you just call `Runnable.run` method directly, then your main thread executes the `run` method, waiting for it's completion and moves to the next instruction. That's why you get a different output. However you can do a little bit of tweak in your code and see it for yourself. Here are the changes you need to make.

```
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ", " + i);
        // Remainder omitted for the sake of brevity.
    }
}
```

What's wrong in your approach is, by just calling `this.getName()` returns the `name` instance field of your thread object, which is just an illusion but not giving you the exact thread which executes your task. If you need to get that, you have to use `Thread.currentThread().getName()` instead. Now here's the output with `start`

```
firstThread, 0  
secondThread, 0
firstThread, 1
secondThread, 1
firstThread, 2
secondThread, 2
```

And here's the output with `run` method

```
main, 0     
main, 1    
main, 2             
main, 0              
main, 1            
main, 2
```

The main thread executes each and every task sequentially. Also if you read the documentation of the `start` method it clearly states,

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls
> the run method of this thread.
>
> The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the current
> thread (which returns from the call to the start method) and the other
> thread (which executes its run method).

Answer (score 0):

`new` just creates an Object of `ThreadTest` and by `run()` you are just calling the run method from the main thread. `new` on Thread class does not create new thread unless start is called.

According to the documentation, run() executes the current thread and start() creates a new thread and executes run() on the new thread.

So when you call start() it creates 2 separate thread and runs them individually. Hence the output:

```
-->firstThread, 0
-->firstThread, 1
-->firstThread, 2
-->secondThread, 0
-->secondThread, 1
-->secondThread, 2
```

Calling run() is simply like calling normal method in the order. Hence the output:

```
-->firstThread, 0
-->secondThread, 0
-->firstThread, 1
-->secondThread, 1
-->firstThread, 2
-->secondThread, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Each Java program running is a process, and the thread that invokes the `main` method called `main thread`.

`run()` method is just like a POJO method which inherited either from `Thread` class or overriden from `Runnable` interface. Calling `run()` method (even from a thread like `thread1.run()`) is not creating a new thread, instead, it simply calls `run()` method from `main` thread.

`start()` method creates a new thread, links it to the object it is called with. In this case `t1.start()`, there is an object `t1` which was just holding a reference address of newly created object.
`start()` creates an object for thread and start and then `run` it.
Hence, in given example code both instance of `start` calling is different as they create two different threads.
While `run` method is invoked from `main` thread, hence the same.

This is the reason for difference in output.